How to maintain a single package version numbers across multiple ROS2 distros?
Assuming you maintain only a single ROS2 package version, i.e. you always keep the sources identical across all ROS2 distros, and you want to release all packages with the same version number on all ROS2 distros. How do you set up the tracks and version numbers when running bloom-release?

Here is @chrisbedard's answer, which boils down to this:

Maintain separate tracks for each distro
Keep only a single branch (named e.g "release") that holds the most recently released version, including the CHANGELOG.rst
To create a new release, git checkout release && git merge <devel_branch>, then run catkin_generate_changelog and catkin_prepare_release as usual.
Now run bloom-release separate for each distro, but when configuring the track, set the upstream branch identical for all distros, e.g. "release".
Note: if you want to switch to this method, bloom-release has a --edit-track feature.
Don't forget to go back and update the doc and source entries in the rosdistro's distribution.yaml to point to the new branch, e.g. release.


Thanks for posting this Q&A here!
